# Paypal recurring payments sandbox set limit to credit cards

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I testing recurring payments on sandbox, with them Negative testing from support page not working. I need fail payment, when credit card don't exceed limit. If I use sandbox account without credit card, it's fails immediately, but I need fail after subscription.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://developer.paypal.com/, if you create a pre-configure sandbox account, all the credit cards you added are confirmed without sending limit.

But if you want to set limit to the credit card in Sandbox environment, you can directly go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ and click Sign Up to register a new unpre-configured Sandbox account, and use virtual credit card generator (you can search from the Internet) to add a credit card on this Sandbox account. Then, such credit card is unconfirmed with sending limit. After that you can continue your recurring payments testing.